# How to aggregate docker logs inside container?

Tags: docker, logging

Which docker logs driver/plugin allow me to store logs in aggregated or deduplicated format which I can inspect inside container like this:

```
$ someLogAnalyzer --popular
log1 134
log2 76
err3 43
err1 13
...
```

Simple and stupid. Without central storage, analitycs and web-interface.

Comment: `docker logs CONTAINER | sort | uniq -c`?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs, old docker logs may have already been removed, that is why we need separate aggregated log